# In javascript, how "for .. in" statement can have side effect?

Tags: javascript, side-effects, javascriptcore

I want to know how `for .. in` can have any side effect?

```js
let arr = [1.1, 2.2];
let obj = {x: 1, y: 1, z: 1};
for(let prop in obj) {
    ...
}
```

Considering above snippet code, is it possible to change some elements in `arr` at `for .. in` statement not in loop body?

I'm currently anaylzing JavaScriptCore JIT Compiler, DFG assumes that `GetPropertyEnumerator` has side-effect, which i understand that it can change some other object at `for .. in` statement.
But, i don't know how is this possible.
So i want to is this possible and if possible, how could i do that.

Comment: If your objects have getters/proxies, those could produce side effects… though that would be stupid getters. But it's a bit unclear whether you're *trying* to change something or whether you want to *avoid* changing something implicitly.

Comment: @deceze Won't getters/proxies only be invoked if `obj[prop]` is accessed (which would occur inside the loop body)?

Comment: @CertainPerformance true for getters, but proxies provide a [has trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/has) which will be triggered by the loop.

Comment: As @CertainPerformance said, getters/proxies are only triggered when object member is accessed.

Comment: And question is updated !

Comment: @Thomas I'm not seeing it https://jsfiddle.net/8g52749c/ Perhaps it only activates when `prop in obj` is used as an *expression*, not as inside a `for` loop declaration. Do you know? Want to post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer for this question myself :)
https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/commit/243a17dd57da84426316502c5346766429f2456d
Above commit log is very helpful for me !

The `Proxy` object has member named `getPrototypeOf`.
By using this `getPrototypeOf`, i can modify some objects during property lookup phase in `for .. in` statement.

```js
let a = {x: 1, y: 2, z: 3};
a.__proto__ = {xx: 1, yy: 2, zz: 3};

for(let i in a) {
    print(i);
}
```

Above one is simple example.
The `for .. in` statement lookup the Object `a`'s properties and then, follow a's __proto__ chain.
In this context, Proxy's `getPrototypeOf` is trap for `__proto__` lookup.
Example is following one.

```js
let a = {
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
  z: 3
};
let p = new Proxy(a, {
  getPrototypeOf: function() {
    console.log("getPrototypeOf - side effects can be caused here");
    return {
      a: 1,
      b: 2
    };
  }
});

for (let i in p) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a gist of the answer here. Without that link, this answer contains no useful content at all.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback :) @deceze

Comment: Cool! I changed your `print(` calls (attempts to print the current page) to `console.log` calls (logs the passed arguments), hope that's OK. You can also set a trap for `ownKeys`, which might be a bit more straightforward.